# How to use ng-repeat with socket.io when you receive message from backend?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, socket.io

I am listening on socket.on , i want to list all the messages that are coming from the backend , I am trying to use ng-repeat to list down all incoming messages but its breaking into alphabet and listing only first message. Any better way to listen socket.io using angularJs ng-repeat or other directive ?

main.html

```
<div class="col-md-4">
            <p ng-repeat="data in message track by $index">{{data}}</p>
 </div>
```

ctrl.js

```
 socket.on('ditConsumer',function (data) {
        $scope.message = data;
        console.log($scope.message);
    });
```

Comment: You would have to trigger a digest cycle as in `$scope.$apply(() => $scope.message = data)`

Comment: How about if i create an array and push data into it and use array in ng-repeat ?

Comment: Should be the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to trigger a digest cycle to append data to the array:

```
socket.on('ditConsumer', data => {
    $scope.$apply(() => $scope.message.push(data));
});
```